# Ошибка синтаксиса js

Tags: javascript

Как исправить проблему? Валидатор ругается

```
const newLeft = e.pageX - shiftX - sliderCoords.left;

    if (newLeft < 0) {
        newLeft = 0;
    }
    const rightEdge = sliderElem.offsetWidth - thumbElem.offsetWidth;
    if (newLeft > rightEdge) {
         newLeft = rightEdge;
    }
```

Ошибка:

> Module build failed: Error: SyntaxError: "newLeft" is read-only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Константа - тип, который можно назначить один раз и читать.
Вы пытаетесь изменять значение константы, а этого делать нельзя. Объявите newLeft через var

Comment: Точно! Спасибо, дебажил просто, и совсем не заметил. Стыдно :\

Comment: Со всеми бывает. Примите мой ответ, если вопрос решен.

Comment: Да, конечно, приму как пройдет 6 мин. Раньше не пускает